# Is there an Oracle equivalent to SQL Server's Application Name Connection String Parameters?

Tags: database, oracle, connection-string

When connecting to a Sql Server you can include either "App" or "Application Name" in the connection string. This makes is *very* easy to trace apps that share a username/password.

One good use for this is Sql Server Profiler. You can filter by application. This has been quite helpful to us in the past.

However, I'm unable to find anything like this for Oracle.

**Is there an equivalent to SQL Server's "Application Name" Connection String Parameters in Oracle?**

*We are using Oracle provided .NET drivers (obviously connecting through .NET/C#) if that is relevant.*

[Microsoft Connection String Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

[Use Application Name parameter when connecting to SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/use-application-name-sql-server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can specify the application name in the connect string.

But if you have the possibility to run a statement inside your application, you can use the [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_appinf.htm) package to set an application name:

```
execute DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('MyProgram');
```

You can also use it to identify different processing steps

```
execute DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('INVOICE', 'Calculating invoiced');
execute DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('CUSTOMER', 'Checking for pending things');
```

This information will show up in `V$SESSION`

Comment: Very sad this isn't settable via the connection string.  That Sql Server Profiler filter on app-name has been a life saver so many times.  Thanks for this by-code workaround.